# How do I find the boot parameters used by the running kernel?

Tags: boot, kernel, grub2

Is there a way to find out with what parameters did the kernel boot?

For example if I specify noexec=off at the grub command line? Can I see this sort of info after the system has finished booting?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48601/how-to-display-kernel-command-line-parameters/423563#423563

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can run `cat /proc/cmdline`.

Example:

```
[01:31] ~ $ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-7-generic root=UUID=025c4231-b7bb-48bf-93e9-d20c5b5ce123 ro crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash bootchart=disable acpi_enforce_resources=lax vga=792 vt.handoff=7
```

Comment: Try `tr ' ' '\n' < /proc/cmdline` to get linebreaks between the parameters.

Answer (score 12):

An alternative way is to check the output of `dmesg` (line 5 here):

```
$ dmesg | grep "Command line"
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-33-generic root=UUID=81dba11f-f76e-4ed4-8120-e6da6328b1ee ro
```

But note that this might not work if many things have been logged (e.g. if the machine has been running for a long time) because initial startup lines may have been pushed out of the ringbuffer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the parameter is located between `__setup_start` and `__setup_end` in the kernel.
In the following code, the `p->str` is the parameter name

**Following kernel code could be found at linux-3.4.5/init/main.c:388**

```c
/* Check for early params. */
static int __init do_early_param(char *param, char *val)
{
    const struct obs_kernel_param *p;
    for (p = __setup_start; p < __setup_end; p++) {
        if ((p->early && parameq(param, p->str)) ||
            (strcmp(param, "console") == 0 &&
             strcmp(p->str, "earlycon") == 0)
        ) {
            if (p->setup_func(val) != 0)
                printk(KERN_WARNING
                       "Malformed early option '%s'\n", param);
        }
    }


    /* We accept everything at this stage. */
    return 0;
}
```